# Rigging taxi cab

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm working on the project and I don't know how to rig a vehicle to animate it. And [I've attached a .blend file to MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/y08623h06n0u5u7,qvapolrpphwvh9q/shared) so you can see my image. Would you be able to help me with this question or point me in the direction where I can find the answer? Hope you can help!

[image]

Actual image of the Taxi in isometric mode

[image: notes on rigging]

Comment: You could use an armature, or simply parent the trunk and wheels to the body and make sure that their origin is at their rotation center, which is already the case. I'm not sure where you're struggling...

Comment: Yes, this task is beautifully explained, but the actual problem is not clearly stated. What have you tried so far? What specifically have you failed at? Please tell a little more about it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Stephan, I think my question is: "How do I add an armature to my object that is already modelled so I can animate it?". Should I have created an armature first? Can I still do it? What I'm trying to do is to get the car moving/animating so I can put it into my video. 

Comment: Please be so kind and add this information to your question (you can edit it at any time), so that the question is complete and the relevant information doesn't just end up in the comments. The order of modeling/armature is not really crucial here, and I'm sure one of the professionals here has a solution for this. I'm more of a *Geometry Nodes* guy, but there are some very capable people here who can solve almost any problem regarding rigging and modeling. ;-)

Comment: Okay thanks, but I'll do some more research and see what I can find...

Comment: you could create an armature but you don't even need to, just do as i said, parent the wheels and trunk to the body and animate